# Cocoa Touch - Timers

Tags: cocoa-touch, nstimer

How can I make a timer that counts down from 3 and then runs a method? How would I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better way might be to use `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` method:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:3.0f];
```

Or in case method takes 1 parameter:

```
[self performSelector:@selector(myMethod:) withObject:parameter afterDelay:3.0f];
```

If method takes multiple parameters you'll need to use `NSInvocation` class

Comment: I choose this as acepted answer because it required the least code. :]

Comment: Note that if you are looking to cancel or stop the selector from executing before the delay has elapsed you may want to look at slf's answer below.

Answer (score 3):

Is that different from a timer counting from 0 to 3?  It will still wait three seconds, either way.

`[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:3.0 target:self selector:@selector(myMethod:) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];`

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void) handleTimer: (NSTimer *) timer
{
    do some work here...
} // handleTimer

// at some point in your controller
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 3.0
                 target: self
                 selector: @selector(handleTimer:)
                 userInfo: nil
                 repeats: NO];
```